# Double counting data in a Bayesian Model? Output is a derived random variable being the product of other observed random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian

I've found a few studies that seem to touch on the possibility of double counting, but have yet to find any examples that fit this exact trope.

That said, is loading observed values in multiple distributions (sites) within a hierarchical Bayesian model allowable (insofar as no significance or signal strengthening is conjured from thin air, i.e. double counting), when the primary “observations” for the estimation of the posterior mean (here =mu[i]) are not derived explicitly from nature etc., but as the arithmetic equation involving the values of other random variables, whose values have actually been observed and whose probability distributions define a lower, or prior tier of distributions within the Bayesian model? (see example shown, however it could be most anything)

**Given a toy example, if:**

Y[i] ~ Norm(mu[i], tau)

mu[i] = v[i] * w[i] * z[i]

**and the priors (variables) are normally distributed and have hyperpriors:**

v[i]~ Norm [mu_v, sd];  Normal, Gamma

w[i] ~Norm [mu_w, sd]; Normal, Gamma

z[I] ~ Norm [mu_z, sd];  Normal, Gamma

**Observations in nature have been made for random variable v[i], w[i] and z[i], for example**

v[n=5]=   {1,2,3,4,5}   w[n=5]=   {1,2,3,4,5}     z[n=5]=   {1,2,3,4,5}

Ergo, giving the aforementioned equation for u[i] (such types of equations are quite common in the life sciences, growth rate, population stuff etc.), the “observations” of the “derived random variable” given the values of v[5], w[5] and z[5] (above) and the following equation

**If:**        mu[i] = v[i] w[i] * z[i]

**Then:**     the corresponding values of ***Y*** which (n=5) sample the mean are 
              determined expressly as {1, 8, 27, 64, 125}

**That being the case, what is the nature of the following scenarios:**

**1)**   Is it “legal”, not double counting etc., to load data for both the observed and "derived random variable"?  If so or if not, in terms of broad strokes theory how could you conclude that answer?

**2)**  Is loading data is more “truthful” in one arrangement?

**3)**  Is there some broader theoretical trope that I’m plainly missing that would even cause me to raise this question?

**4)**  Thnx for the feedback!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CV! Just a small remark: Using simpler English may attract more answers. You first sentence is very difficult to read due to its length and the choice of words.

Comment: Using LaTeX would make the question more readable as well.

Comment: Hi Frans. Apologies I will certainly keep that in mind!  Additionally, there is a key period missing between the first and second sentences (between "trope" (.) and "Is").  Probably good to make sure one's first sentence is grammatically correct before the post goes live next time : ^ } Is there any way to do post-submission edits on a post as to clean it up if an error is noticed?

Comment: There is an edit link just under the question on the left (share, cite, edit, flag)

Answer (score 1):

**This is not double-counting.** If you observe the values of $v_i$, $w_i$, and $z_i$, then (a) they are not strictly speaking prior quantities and (b) you should use them to make inference on the parameters $\mu_v$, &tc., while you can use the sample of the $y_i$'s to make inference on $\tau$.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for responding again out of the blue, however I just wanted to let you know I finally came across a paper that exactly articulates the question I posed some days ago and provided a concrete solution, within my general field no less!  It does seem to evoke a rather esoteric application of Bayesian infrence, but that is coming from my rather modest introduction to the larger field of statistics  Anyway I though you may appreciate it, I shall let it speak for itself: [link](https://www.stat.washington.edu/raftery/Research/PDF/rgz1995.pdf)